# My passport auth doesnt work on Heroku, user is not returned

Tags: node.js, authentication, heroku, passport.js, passport-local

My app and auth is working perfectly localy, however after deploying the server to heroku I am unable to login, because user object is not returned.

Here is my passport file:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    // console.log({user})
    done(null, user._id)
})


passport.deserializeUser((id, done) =>
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        if (user) {
            done(null, user)
        } else {
        }
    })
);

passport.use(new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    // console.log({username}, {password})
    User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Username not found' });
        }

        if (!user.comparePassword(password, user.password)) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }
        // console.log('user', user)
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

Routes:

```
const passport = require('passport');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

module.exports = (app) => {
 app.post('/login',
        passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
            failureRedirect: '/loginFailed',
        })
    );

    app.get('/loginSuccess', (req, res) => {
        res.send({ success: true, test:'test', user: req.user })
    })
    app.get('/loginFailed', (req, res) => {
        res.send({ success: false, error: "Incorrect credentials" })
    })

};
```

And I dont know if its helpful, but my index file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

const keys = require('./config/keys');

require('./models/user');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true })

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 + 60 * 60 * 1000, //30 days
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//ROUTES
require('./routes/auth')(app);
require('./routes/game')(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

After login is successfull I send back object containing 3 other objects, success bool value, user object with user info and for the sake of testing, test object containing a string.

Everything is returned, except for user object. What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you check if the session cookie is set properly after you logged in?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?